# JavaFX IntelliJ module compile Error on Mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run a simple JavaFX program on IntelliJ on a Mac.

On the runtime I have put the following command for the VM options

```
--module-path="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib"
--add-modules="javafx.controls"
```

[image]

this i the code and the file structure on the side

[image]

the controller is an empty class

But I keep getting this error:

[image]

Comment: could you please show the code of the "simple javafx program" please? Due to the log you running JDK 11 and JavaFX is not integrated since JDK10 anymore, so it's kinda difficult where the root of the issue is ;)

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not properly structured it's the first time I'm asking on Stack Overflow

Comment: no worries, hmm can't really check you code if it's working or not atm. but i will tomorrow if nobody response ;) some stuff that makes me wonder: 1. why is your "layout" not attached to you Program? (instead you have attached "root"...makes no sense to me oO? ) 2. you need to decide if you want to use a funk loader or not? if the controller is empty then remove this

Comment: CrissCrossCrass i fixed it. you were right I had too much confusion in the code with the layout and the root. I went over it rewrote it and its works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great! glad it works now, good luck for further development! ;)